# Listas encadeadas em C

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Possuo duas listas em C, onde deve se incluir varios registros na lista de clientes, e fazer depois com que esse algum cliente consiga reservar um carro que fica armazenado na lista de carros. A parte de inclusão, remoção e visualização de clientes eu consigo fazer de boa, o problema é na hora de fazer com que o cliente consiga reservar um carro, ou seja a celula com o nome do cliente apontar para a lista com nome do carro reservado.

```
 struct carro
{
        int codigo;
        char modelo[30];
        struct carro *proximo;
};

struct cliente
{
        int codigo;
        char nome[50];
        struct cliente *proximo;
        struct carro *reserva;
};


// Inserir no inicio da lista; 
struct cliente* insereInicio(struct cliente *pInicio,int codigo, char nome[50]){

        struct cliente *aux;
        aux = (struct cliente *)malloc(sizeof(struct cliente));
        aux->codigo = codigo;
        strcpy(aux->nome,nome);
        aux->proximo = pInicio;
        pInicio = aux;
        return pInicio;
}

void insereDepois(struct cliente *p, int codigo, char nome[50])
{
        struct cliente *aux;

        aux= (struct cliente *) malloc(sizeof(struct cliente));

        aux ->codigo=codigo;
        strcpy(aux->nome,nome);
        aux ->proximo=p->proximo;
        p->proximo=aux;

}  

struct cliente* insereOrdenado(struct cliente *pInicio, int codigo, char nome[50]){
        struct cliente *p, *q;
        if(pInicio == NULL || codigo < pInicio->codigo){
                return (insereInicio(pInicio, codigo, nome));          
        }
        p = pInicio;
        q = p;
        while(q != NULL && q->codigo > codigo){
                p = q;
                q = p->proximo;
        }
        if(q == NULL || q->codigo < codigo){
                insereDepois(p,codigo,nome);
        }
        else{
                printf("\nElemento ja existe");
        }
        return (pInicio);
}

main()
{
        struct ciiente *inicio;
        inicio = NULL;

        int opcao = 0;
        int codigo;
        char nome[50];

        while(1)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("-----# Bem Vindo #-----\n");
            printf("\n1 - Incluir Cliente");
            printf("\n2 - Listar clientes");
            printf("\n3 - Sair do Programa\n");
            scanf("%d",&opcao);

            if(opcao == 1) {
                system("cls");
                printf("-----# Inserir novo Cliente #-----\n");
                printf("\nDigite o codigo do cliente: ");
                scanf("%d",&codigo);
                printf("Digite o nome do Cliente: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",nome);

                inicio = insereOrdenado(inicio, codigo, nome);
            }   
            else if(opcao == 2)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("-----# Clientes Cadastrados #-----\n");
                percorreLista(inicio);
            }
            else if(opcao == 3)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Meu problema é que não faço a minima ideia de como fazer para minha lista de clientes apontar para determinado nó da minha lista de carros, então gostaria de saber se alguem poderia me orientar a como fazer isso exatamente.

OBS: Sou novato em C.

Comment: Para fazer a reserva, o usuário vai informar o código do cliente e o código do carro? Um carro pode ser reservado para duas pessoas ao mesmo tempo (suponho que não)?

Comment: Isso, primeiro voce informa o codigo do cliente e depois o codigo do carro para que o mesmo possa ser reservado. E o mesmo carro não pode ser reservado para duas pessoas ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, você terá que mudar o `struct carro` para dizer quem é que o reservou:

```
struct cliente;

struct carro
{
    int codigo;
    char modelo[30];
    struct carro *proximo;
    struct cliente *reservado;
};

struct reserva
{
    struct reserva *proximo;
    struct carro *carro;
};

struct cliente
{
    int codigo;
    char nome[50];
    struct cliente *proximo;
    struct reserva *reserva;
};
```

Observe que a primeira declaração `struct cliente` é necessária porque `carro` referencia `cliente` e `cliente` referencia `carro`. Essa é a forma de fazer o compilador aceitar a dependência cíclica.

A estrutura `reserva` serve para eu ter uma lista de carros para cada pessoa.

Vamos colocar duas funções de busca por código:

```
struct carro *localizarCarroPorCodigo(int codigo, struct carro *primeiro) {
    for (struct carro *c = primeiro; c != NULL; c = c->proximo) {
        if (c->codigo == codigo) return c;
    }
    return NULL;
}


struct carro *localizarClientePorCodigo(int codigo, struct cliente *primeiro) {
    for (struct cliente *c = primeiro; c != NULL; c = c->proximo) {
        if (c->codigo == codigo) return c;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Agora, fazemos a função de reserva:

```
void reservarCarro(int codigoCliente, int codigoCarro, struct cliente *primeiroCliente, struct carro *primeiroCarro) {
    struct cliente *cl = localizarClientePorCodigo(codigoCliente, primeiroCliente);
    if (cl == NULL) {
        printf("Nao existe o cliente com o codigo %d.", codigoCliente);
        return;
    }

    struct carro *ca = localizarCarroPorCodigo(codigoCarro, primeiroCarro);
    if (ca == NULL) {
        printf("Nao existe o carro com o codigo %d.", codigoCarro);
        return;
    }

    if (ca->reservado != NULL) {
        printf("Este carro ja esta reservado.");
        return;
    }

    struct reserva *nova = (struct reserva *) malloc(sizeof(struct reserva));
    nova->carro = ca;
    nova->proximo = cl->reserva;
    cl->reserva = nova;
    ca->reservado = cl;
    printf("Reserva efetuada com sucesso.");
}
```

E também é importante fazer a função de liberar uma reserva. Essa daí é parecida com a anterior, mas é mais fácil. Partindo do código do carro, você acha o cliente. E então você retira o carro da lista de reserva e coloca o cliente do carro para `NULL`. Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
void liberarCarro(int codigoCarro, struct carro *primeiroCarro) {
    struct carro *ca = localizarCarroPorCodigo(codigoCarro, primeiroCarro);
    if (ca == NULL) {
        printf("Nao existe o carro com o codigo %d.", codigoCarro);
        return;
    }

    struct client *cl = ca->reservado;
    if (cl == NULL) {
        printf("Este carro nao estava reservado.");
        return;
    }

    struct reserva *r = NULL;
    struct reserva *s = cl->reserva;
    while (s != NULL) {
        if (s->carro == ca) {
            if (r != NULL) r->proximo = s->proximo;
            if (s == cl->reserva) cl->reserva = s->proximo;
            free(s);
            break;
        }
        r = s;
        s = s->proximo;
    }
    ca->reservado = NULL;
    printf("Reserva liberada com sucesso.");
}
```

E na hora de inserir o cliente, é importante certificar-se que o código seja único. Uma forma de fazer é na hora de inserir o cliente, procurar um cliente com aquele código e só deixar fazer a inserção se não encontrar (ou seja, a busca der como resultado `NULL`). O mesmo vale para o carro. Uma outra estratégia é fazer com que o programa gere os códigos automaticamente ao invés de pedir que o usuários os digite e então o programa informa os códigos gerados para o usuário.

Para listar todos os carros de um cliente:

```
void listarCarros(struct cliente *cliente) {
    for (struct reserva *s = cl->reserva; s != NULL; s = s->proximo) {
        printf("Codigo: %d - Modelo: %s", s->carro->codigo, s->carro->modelo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma ai, o programa não permitiria mais de uma reserva para o mesmo cliente certo?

Comment: @DanLima certo. Olhando o seu `struct cliente` do seu código original, presumi que isso é intencional. Se não for, me fale que eu altero o código de acordo.

Comment: Na realidade, a intenção é o cliente poder reservar mais de um carro ao mesmo tempo, desde que o carro ja não esteja reservado para outro cliente. Compreende?

Comment: Consegui implementar para inserir mais de um carro para um cliente, porem não consigo listar os carros que foram reservados para determinado cliente. Não faço ideia de como printar o que esta no cliente->reserva. Alguma ideia?

Comment: @DanLima Resposta editada.

Comment: Como eu faria se eu quisesse listar todos os carros reservados para um cliente? Ja tentei um " while(p->reserva != NULL)" imprimindo os modelos dos carros dentro do loop, porem o programa para de executar.

Comment: @DanLima Resposta editada de novo.